# Exporting rules from Outlook into text file

Tags: outlook, export, rules

We have lots of rules in Outlook functional mailbox and we wanted to export them into clear text for review purposes. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks,

EddieT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not unless you write some code to do that.